# PHPUnit Plugin not found PhpStorm

Tags: debugging, plugins, phpunit, settings, phpstorm

---

When I run the debugger on PhpStorm I get:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1
>   -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /private/var/folders/b8/xt21vdh94pbc6ht731dh5k_h0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php
>   --no-configuration /Users/Amit/Web/WPML.beta Testing started at 9:04 PM ...
>
> Process finished with exit code 1 Cannot find PHPUnit in include path
>   (.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php)

In the Settings I do not see the PHPUnit plugin (image attached)

[image: screenshot]

Any idea what's next?

Comment: **1)** PHPUnit support is part of the PHP support itself -- there is no separate plugin **2)** PHPUnit is not found on your computer -- it has NOTHING to do with IDE -- PhpStorm does not come with it's own PHP or PHPUnit. Have you installed it or downloaded in any way (e.g. via Composer or as PHAR file)?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation from phpstorm is missleading, as they just describe how to set up phpunit for new projects. If you try to add this to an existing project, it isn't working.
phpunit is part of the mamp installation and can be found under /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/phpunit.phar

**Settings in PHPStorm:**

*For existing Projects:*

PhpStorm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit

*For new Projects:*

File -> Default Settings... -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit

Select Path to phpunit.phar Radiobutton
Set Path to /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/phpunit.phar

Click Apply to save changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the location of PHPUnit within the IDE. So in version 9.0.2 for example got to Preferences>Languages & Frameworks>PHP>PHPUnit

I fixed the problem by selecting the "Path to phpunit.phar" and specifying the path to where I have the executable located.

You can download it if need be from the PHPUnit site, and my version of PHPStorm prompts you to do this, supplying the direct URL.